# Bootstrap 3 Form fill parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to write a navbar in Bootstrap 3, there is a navbar and some brand and other stuff including a search form in it
I want the search form to fill the extra space in navbar, what should i do?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
      <input type="search" class="form-control search-box">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
    </form>
    <div class="navbar-form btn-group pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">User</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `span` classes?

Comment: I dont want fixed elements, I just want the search input to fill extra space

Comment: You are floating the wrapper of the search bar, which will always force the wrapper to shrink to the size of its contents. That is how floating works in CSS; it's not necessarily a Bootstrap issue. Try removing `pull-left` from the first `<form>`.

Answer (score 4):

A lot has changed with Bootstrap 3. You need to specify widths for inputs. You can try something like...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button> 
            <input type="search" class="form-control pull-left" style="width:70%;"> 
          </form>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/70142

Comment: Ty, not what I was looking for, but the best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because your menu is fixed to the top, you can use something like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" 
       style="display:inline; 
              position:absolute; 
              margin-right: 140px;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

The display:inline is used that the absolute position is directly next to your left navbar-brand or maybe a nav navbar-nav. The class form-control of bootstrap will use it's 100% width to fill the rest of the navbar with the input field. Because you have got a dropdown on the right side of form define a matching margin to the right, so the element does not overlap.

Example: [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/trBuNj9DuouTrcuhfxVw?p=preview)

It works with IE and Chrome but unfortunately **not on Firefox and Safari**. Ideas how to fix this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
            <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User  <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```